# ¿Cómo transformo un conjunto en vector?

Tags: python-3.7

estamos ocupando python 3.6, y queremos transformar conjuntos a vectores, por ej, tngo el conjunto D={100, 50, 70} y quiero pasarlo a vector...como se hace eso?
quedaría como una lista? D=[100,50,70] o se cambia la variable que ya había definido previamente como un conjunto?, o se hace mediante un alias o de otra forma?
Si alguien puede ayudar 
le estaremos muy agradecidos

Answer (score 0):

Haría falta un poco más de contexto para comprender qué quieres hacer, pues algunas de tus preguntas no se entienden y la propia idea de convertir conjunto en vector es un poco sorprendente, por lo que explicaré a continuación.

Primero haría falta saber qué entiendes por vector. Si bien es cierto que en muchos contextos (cursos de programación y algunos lenguajes) vector es equivalente a "array unidimensional" y por tanto en Python equivalente a "lista", en matemáticas en cambio (y en ciertas bibliotecas de carácter matemático) un vector es algo más, al tener definidas una serie de operaciones (como el producto vectorial o el producto escalar, etc)

Si te refieres a una simple lista, bastaría hacer:

```
conjunto = {100, 50, 70}
lista = list(conjunto)
```

Pero si te refieres a un "vector matemático", la conversión no tiene mucho sentido. En un vector los elementos están ordenados, pues según la posición dentro del vector representan una coordenada en una dimensión diferente. Por ejemplo, en un vector de tres componentes típicamente el primero corresponde al eje x, el segundo al eje y y el tercero al eje z. Es decir, el vector tiene un *orden interno* en el que no es lo mismo decir `[1, 2, 3]` que `[3, 2, 1]`. Serían vectores diferentes.

En cambio los conjuntos, por definición, no tienen orden. El conjunto `{100, 50, 70}` contiene al elemento `100`, pero este no es necesariamente el primero. No importa en qué orden los escriba, pues simplemente el conjunto recordará qué elementos tiene, pero no en qué posiciones. En la práctica, eso significa que al convertirlo en lista, el resultado puede ser diferente cada vez. Por ejemplo, al ejecutar el programa que puse más arriba, a mi me sale `lista = [50, 100, 70]`, que como ves no sigue el mismo orden que el conjunto de entrada. Y lo que es peor, en otra ejecución del mismo script puede salir otro orden.

En cuanto a tus otras preguntas:

> o se cambia la variable que ya había definido previamente como un conjunto?

Esto no lo entiendo. ¿Quieres decir que si tienes `D = {100, 50, 70}` y haces `D = list(D)` cambiará el valor de `D`? Obviamente sí, pues le estas asignando uno nuevo. Pero no creo que estés preguntando esto.

> o se hace mediante un alias o de otra forma?

Esto del alias tampoco lo entiendo. Pero si lo que te preocupa es perder el valor de la variable D, basta que asignes el resultado a otra variable, por ejemplo `V = list(D)`. Eso dejará `D` como estaba y creará una nueva variable `V` que será una lista (con los mismos elementos que `D` pero en cualquier otro orden como ya vimos).

Una nota final, un conjunto no guarda elementos repetidos. Si el 1 era un elemento de `D`, al añadirlo otra vez con `D.add(1)`, el conjunto no cambia. Por tanto el conjunto `{1,1,1}` no puede existir (sería en realidad el conjunto `{1}`) mientras que el vector `[1,1,1]` sí que podría existir. Por eso no veo mucho sentido a lo de convertir conjuntos en vectores.

Comment: Abulafia...gracias por responder rapido...la verdad es que si, no me expliqué bien, pero ,me refería

Comment: Abulafia...gracias por responder rápido...la verdad es que si, no me expliqué bien, pero me refería justamente a eso de hacer como una transformación sin perder los valores de la lista...y sí, no me expliqué bien, porque en realidad no me manejo muy bien en python, pero muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó a entender un par de cosas ;) Saludos